# How to style buttons in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Button is as follows:

```
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
```

In follow_form:

```
    <%= render 'follow' %>
```

In follow.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @user.id),
         :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Watch" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

How would I style that with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass parameters to the `f.submit` helper, including a class and/or ID, to enable the button to be styled by CSS.  For example, you could put this in the ERB:

```
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Watch", :class => "button" %></div>
```

and then have a CSS class that applies to that, for example:

```
.button{
  color: #bbbbbb;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  /*add any other properties you want to style*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
<%= f.submit "Watch" , :style => 'padding-top: 14px', :class => 'class_name' %>
```

Comment: What if I was trying to style color, size, round edges..etc..? TY

Comment: add style like : 'color:#FFF;fonst-size:12px;' or make class into css and add the class_name .