# How to style an image tag in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image tag as follows:

```
    <%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:large) %>
```

How could I style a border color to one side of that image in CSS? What html would that produce?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136487/how-to-style-buttons-in-ruby-on-rails/10136528#10136528

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style buttons in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136487/how-to-style-buttons-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add a class or id to your image_tag:

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:large), :class => "style_image" %>
```

Then use css to style it:

```
.style_image {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 81):

by using "style" option:

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:large), :style => "border: 1px solid red" %>
```

for further info, please check the API.

Answer (score 13):

you can also give inline style as well

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:large), :style => "float :left;border 1px solid #00000;" %>
```

Try it.....

Answer (score 13):

In newer versions of Rails, there is a "better" way:

```
<%= image_tag('filename_in_public_folder', alt: 'Description', style: 'display: block; margin: auto; width: 40%;')%>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple way to do it.

```
<%= image_tag("example.png", :style => 'border-right: 1px solid #000;')%>
```

Answer (score 1):

For others who come across this on Google.
If you use an image tag in a different way, you can still add css class to it, but it's just different syntax.  Sometimes you need to use an external server.  (Deployment on Heroku? => Amazon s3)

```
<%= image_tag("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucketname/user_photo.png", class: "style_image") %>
```